# Публикация приложения в Google Play и авторизация

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, auth, firebase-android

После публикации Android приложения в Google Play перестала работать Google авторизация. Если запускать приложение из Android Studio, то всё работает и прекрасно входит; Если скачать с Google Play, то уже не работает. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой или знает как такое решается.

Comment: а не тестовый ли дебажный json лежит в приложении?

Comment: @IlyaBaikalow У вас в корне проекта должен лежать json полученный от гугла.

Comment: при подключении firebase (судя по тегу) используется json на этапе сборки. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592 ну а дальше советую ещё раз всю интеграцию перечитать

Comment: @pavel скачал новый файл json, пересобрал, ничего не изменилось. Еще заметил, что не работает подписанный файл, хотя неподписанный работает

Comment: значит скорее всего у вас json для неподписанного (а точнее подписанного тестовым сертификатом) сгенерирован.

Comment: @pavel подскажи, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно, чтоб был для подписанного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то подобное у меня было ещё до интеграции Firebase со студией.

Не надо сейчас вручную качать .json. Просто авторизуйтесь в студии с аккаунта разработчика, и она сама подтянет конфигурацию для вашего приложения, сама положит его в нужное место, и если есть ошибки подключения, покажет вам их.

Вам остаётся только выбрать какой функционал использовать (Analytics, Admob и т.д.) и следовать инструкциям подключения.

Comment: Да, вы частично правы, я совсем забыл связать c firebase. Также, как и говорил @pavel, я использовал дебажную версию вместо релизной. Когда все исправил, все стало работать